# React mapping is returning first element from the array

Tags: reactjs

Can someone please assist, I've been search for some time now and can't seem to solve the issue. I'm trying to get each element (playName, id) but I keep receiving this message:

> react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid
> as a React child (found: object with keys {playName, id}). If you
> meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I also keep getting the first elements (playName, id) from the bangerList but thats it, there's 8 I need to output. I am relatively new to react and would love some help.

Thanks
Luke

```
getCurrentUser(){
        Spotify.getCurrentUser().then(res => {
            // Need to get each playName element from the res
           console.log(res)
            res.map(bangerList =>{
                console.log(bangerList)
                this.setState({
                    bangerList: bangerList
                })
            })
       });
    }


    handleNameChange(e){
      this.props.onNameChange(e.target.value)
    };

    render(){
        return (
        <div className="Playlist">
            <input onChange={this.handleNameChange} 
                defaultValue={"Playlist name"}
            />
            <TrackList tracks={this.props.playlistTracks} 
                onRemove={this.props.onRemove} 
                isRemoval={true} 
            />
            <button className="Playlist-save" onClick={this.props.onSave}>SAVE TO SPOTIFY</button>
          <MyBangers addit={this.getCurrentUser} 
          bangerListItems = {this.state.bangerList}
          />

        </div>
        
        
        
        
        
class MyBangers extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

this.getHandler = this.getHandler.bind(this);

    }
// all this needs to go to app.js---------------
    getHandler(){
       
}    


// ---------------------------------------------

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="myPlaylist">
                <h2>My Bangers</h2>
                <div>
                    {
                        
                        }
                    
                </div>
                <h3 className="hoverPlay">{this.props.bangerListItems}</h3>
            <button onClick={this.props.addit}>click me</button>
                
        </div>
        )
```

Comment: How does `bangerListItems ` look like? Please include data in code

Comment: Include the code for `MyBangers` component, also in the map function, in each iteration you are overwriting `bangerList` state. Note that `setState` is an asynchronous task.

Comment: This is MyBangers component


class MyBangers extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

this.getHandler = this.getHandler.bind(this);

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="myPlaylist">
                <h2>My Bangers</h2>
                
                <h3 className="hoverPlay">{this.props.bangerListItems}</h3>
            <button onClick={this.props.addit}>click me</button>
                
        </div>
        )
    }   
}

Comment: This is my response 

(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {playName: 'My Playlist', id: '3JSYbgBD2qU46WNB9p7UHS'}
1: {playName: 'My Playlist', id: '13fWmocvqL1TxIAIlWP98K'}
2: {playName: 'My Playlist', id: '7f5R2gRVtXxRROSCarNNmK'}
3: {playName: 'My Playlist', id: '3E6nCP1UZNdKAlpqGIhSYO'}
4: {playName: 'My Playlist', id: '1v9xaa4f1FOjoEKoEP8iHv'}
5: {playName: 'Lukes list', id: '0lFsfL90hP39aoZluvuDUU'}
6: {playName: 'My Playlist', id: '2rtRMbzb4GSK7qat6DR1j6'}
7: {playName: 'Poetic Justice', id: '6nwhhAYmbQmyiVCPvTTes8'}
length: 8
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: And when I console.log this is what my bangerListItem returns 

{playName: 'My Playlist', id: '3JSYbgBD2qU46WNB9p7UHS'}
id: "3JSYbgBD2qU46WNB9p7UHS"
playName: "My Playlist"
[[Prototype]]: Object